# How to create a list of widgets with their own distinct TextEditingController() that you can access?

Tags: flutter

I have a listview of widgets that contain a TextField(), but when you edit one TextField(), it changes every other TextField() to be exactly like the one you just edited. How can I create a distinct TextEditingController() that I am able to access from each item in the list?

I have a list of widgets as follows, with a controller variable for user input in a TextField:

```
final List<Widget> _setsList = [];
TextEditingController repsController = TextEditingController
```

I am pushing a new widget 'createSetCard' below when the user presses a button and saving their input in the TextEditingController:

```
Widget createSetCard() {
  return Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            setNumber.toString(),
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: constants.kHunterColor),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: TextField(
          controller:repsController,
          enabled: tf,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          maxLength: 3,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            isDense: true,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 40),
            hintText: "reps",
            // suffix: Text('reps'),
            counterText: "",
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const Expanded(
        child: Center(child: Text("x")),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: TextField(
          controller: lbsController,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          maxLength: 3,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            isDense: true,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 40),
            hintText: "lbs",
            suffix: Text("lbs"),
            counterText: "",
            border: InputBorder.none,
            //suffix: Text('lbs'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

My question is when I have multiple items being displayed in my ListView, each of the items changes when I change one of the input fields. How can I make each input field separate from one another in the List? As shown below, each TextField in the ListView is being edited when I change any value of any item in the list.

[image]

Comment: plz share code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `TextField` are controlled by a `TextEditingController`, you have multiple `TextField` but using same `TextEditingController`.

To solve this, you need to create differences `TextEditingController` for each `TextField`.

**Example**: Simple widget that contains a dynamic list that allow to edit value with multiple `TextField`.

**UPDATE**: Update Inputor to able to use 2 `TextField` each row. You can check editing history to see differences.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: App()));

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AppState createState() => AppState();
}

class AppState extends State<App> {
  var inputors = <Inputor>[
    Inputor(1, initialFirstName: 'Jon', initialLastName: 'Smith'),
    Inputor(2, initialFirstName: 'Nguyen', initialLastName: 'Van'),
    Inputor(3, initialFirstName: 'Tran'),
  ];

  void addNewInputor() {
    setState(() {
      var newId = inputors.last.id + 1;
      inputors.add(Inputor(newId));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          ...inputors.map(renderInputor).toList(),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: addNewInputor,
            child: const Text('Add new inputor'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget renderInputor(Inputor inputor) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text("Inputor [${inputor.id}]"),
        subtitle: Row(children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 4,
            child: TextField(
              controller: inputor.firstNameController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'First name'),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 20),
          Flexible(
            flex: 6,
            child: TextField(
              controller: inputor.lastNameController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last name'),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Inputor {
  int id;
  TextEditingController firstNameController;
  TextEditingController lastNameController;
  Inputor(this.id, {String initialFirstName = '', String initialLastName = ''})
      : firstNameController = TextEditingController(text: initialFirstName),
        lastNameController = TextEditingController(text: initialLastName);
  String get firstName => firstNameController.text;
  String get lastName => lastNameController.text;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much. How much more complicated would this be if you were to add two textfields per line? So for each new inputer in the list, you would have 2 text fields that need to be filled instead of one.

Comment: @Xalec completely easy, just add more controller in `Inputor`. i was updated the answer. Dont forget upvote and accept the answer if it help solve your problem.

Comment: thank you so much. Great answer, I appreciate you!